# PyTorch Lightning Code Throws Error When I Train on Multiple GPUs

Tags: pytorch, distributed-computing, pytorch-lightning, dataparallel

Below is my code for training a PyTorch model on multiple GPUs with Lightning. First, I define the architecture of the neural network, which consists of two fully connected layers for a basic classification task. Then, I created a data module to handle the loading and preprocessing of the MNIST dataset. The data module takes care of creating data loaders for both training and validation datasets. Next, I initialize a PyTorch Lightning Trainer, specifying that I want to use two GPUs (GPU 0 and GPU 1) for training, and I use data parallelism ('dp') as the distributed backend. Finally, I train the model using the trainer.fit method with the data module I created.

```html
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import pytorch_lightning as pl

class SimpleNN(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleNN, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(784, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        inputs, labels = batch
        outputs = self(inputs)
        loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(outputs, labels)
        self.log('train_loss', loss)
        return loss

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.001)
        return optimizer

class MNISTDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self, batch_size=64):
        super(MNISTDataModule, self).__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def setup(self, stage=None):
        from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
        from torchvision import transforms
        self.transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))])
        self.mnist_train = MNIST(root='./data', train=True, transform=self.transform, download=True)
        self.mnist_test = MNIST(root='./data', train=False, transform=self.transform, download=True)

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.mnist_train, batch_size=self.batch_size, shuffle=True)

    def val_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.mnist_test, batch_size=self.batch_size)

    def test_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.mnist_test, batch_size=self.batch_size)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    model = SimpleNN()
    data_module = MNISTDataModule(batch_size=64)
    trainer = pl.Trainer(devices=[0, 1], max_epochs=5, strategy='ddp_notebook')
    trainer.fit(model, datamodule=data_module)
```

However, I get the error

```html
ProcessRaisedException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/henry/dev/training/notebook.ipynb Cell 23 in ()
     60 trainer = pl.Trainer(devices=[0, 1], max_epochs=5, strategy='ddp_notebook')
     62 # Train the model on multiple GPUs
---> 63 trainer.fit(model, datamodule=data_module)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py:532, in Trainer.fit(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path)
    530 self.strategy._lightning_module = model
    531 _verify_strategy_supports_compile(model, self.strategy)
--> 532 call._call_and_handle_interrupt(
    533     self, self._fit_impl, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path
    534 )

File ~/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py:42, in _call_and_handle_interrupt(trainer, trainer_fn, *args, **kwargs)
     40 try:
     41     if trainer.strategy.launcher is not None:
---> 42         return trainer.strategy.launcher.launch(trainer_fn, *args, trainer=trainer, **kwargs)
     43     return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
     45 except _TunerExitException:

File ~/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/launchers/multiprocessing.py:127, in _MultiProcessingLauncher.launch(self, function, trainer, *args, **kwargs)
    119 process_context = mp.start_processes(
    120     self._wrapping_function,
    121     args=process_args,
   (...)
    124     join=False,  # we will join ourselves to get the process references
    125 )
    126 self.procs = process_context.processes
--> 127 while not process_context.join():
    128     pass
    130 worker_output = return_queue.get()

File ~/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py:160, in ProcessContext.join(self, timeout)
    158 msg = "\n\n-- Process %d terminated with the following error:\n" % error_index
    159 msg += original_trace
--> 160 raise ProcessRaisedException(msg, error_index, failed_process.pid)

ProcessRaisedException: 

-- Process 0 terminated with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/henry/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 69, in _wrap
    fn(i, *args)
  File "/home/henry/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/launchers/multiprocessing.py", line 153, in _wrapping_function
    results = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/henry/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 571, in _fit_impl
    self._run(model, ckpt_path=ckpt_path)
  File "/home/henry/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 938, in _run
    self.strategy.setup_environment()
  File "/home/henry/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/ddp.py", line 144, in setup_environment
    super().setup_environment()
  File "/home/henry/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/strategy.py", line 129, in setup_environment
    self.accelerator.setup_device(self.root_device)
  File "/home/henry/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/cuda.py", line 44, in setup_device
    _check_cuda_matmul_precision(device)
  File "/home/henry/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightning_fabric/accelerators/cuda.py", line 349, in _check_cuda_matmul_precision
    major, _ = torch.cuda.get_device_capability(device)
  File "/home/henry/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 381, in get_device_capability
    prop = get_device_properties(device)
  File "/home/henry/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 395, in get_device_properties
    _lazy_init()  # will define _get_device_properties
  File "/home/henry/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 235, in _lazy_init
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method
```

I seem to be missing how to enable multiprocessing spawning in this context and have tried various approaches including manually setting it up as shown in the code. I still get the same error nonetheless and would really appreciate some guidance on what I am missing.